# Why xcode not show errors when call undeclared methods?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I start a new project with a default `Xcode` template ,
I test code like this

```
-(void)test{
    NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [a  nosuchmethod];        
}
```

`Xcode` shows an error like `"No visible....."`
but in another existing project , I test those code again, but `xcode` only complains a warning

why did this happen? 
Are there any settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ARC enabled project/file, you cannot call no existed method except on `id` object. This does not apply for non-ARC project. Also, new project are default to be ARC enabled so you can't do it in new project.

for example, this is not allowed in ARC enabled project/file

```
NSString *str = @"str";
[str appendString:@"str"];
```

you can do this, but it will crash/throw exception if this line is executed

```
[(id)str appendString:@"str"];
```

Comment: sorry for late.......accept yet